# Fix bread crumbs to header

Tags: css, angular, bootstrap-4

I want to fix bread crumbs to top of navbar. Developing application using angular, bootstrap 4.

app.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-toggleable-lg navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top" style="position:sticky">
  <!--navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top -->


  <!-- Important - make sure to have the toggler button outside of the container -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
    <!--aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"-->
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div>

    <span class="navbar-text" style="color:white">Header</span>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid" style="padding-left:0px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
      <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 x1-sidebar bg-dark" style="position:sticky;">
        <app-navbar></app-navbar>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

app-navbar is a vertical navigation component.

router-outlet is the main content. It has dynamic breadcrumbs and content.

Below is breadcrumbs and content:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" *ngIf="breadCrumbs?.length>0" style="position:inherit;">
        <div class="col">
            <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                <ul class="breadcrumb bg-dark sticky-top" >
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item" *ngFor='let breadcrumb of breadCrumbs; let i = index' >
                        <a >{{ Dynamic breadcrumb label }}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            //content.......
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if code is not clear. I will give more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.breadcrumb {
    position: fixed;
    top: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Then depending on the height of your header adjust the value of 40px in that code.